# JTable Model data not showing Updated data

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, defaulttablemodel

my Swing application has few textfileds and Jtable. When I update the values in textFileds those values not showing on Jtable immediately after updating data. 
I tried using tbmodel.fireTableDataChanged(); But that didnt work.

```
 try {
              String driveID = txtDriverID.getText();
              String trnsCompName = (String)cmbTransCompany.getSelectedItem();
              String trDriverName = txtName.getText();
              String trAddress = txtAddress.getText();
              String trDob = txtDOB.getText();
              String license = txtLicence.getText();
              String telephone = txtTelephone.getText();
              PvtTransportDriver pvtDriver = new PvtTransportDriver(driveID, trnsCompName, trDriverName, trAddress, trDob, license, telephone);
              int res = PvtTransDriverController.updatePvtTransportDriver(pvtDriver);
              tbmodel = (DefaultTableModel) tblAllPvtDrivers.getModel();
              tbmodel.fireTableDataChanged();
              if (res > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");
              }
        } catch (    ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(PvtTransDriver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is is not necessary to call `fireTableDataChanged`. This is called by the `TableModel`.

For updating table rows you can use [setValueAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

For adding rows you can use [addRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

For example:

```
tbmodel.setValueAt(driveID, 0, 0);
```

Comment: thnx for your reply. But thts not the case here. I have separate method to insert data to tabel using setValueAt method. what i want to do is when i press update button on interface, text field data should update relavant database fields. Table data comes from database, not from textfields. So i want update table data just after i update database using text fields.

Comment: Then you will need to make an `SQL` `INSERT` or `UPDATE` call, preferably using a PreparedStatement. See this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html)